# Safari incorrect sizing with rem and animation

Tags: html, css, safari, bootstrap-4

**EDIT:** *I have just discovered that it seams to work correctly inside the SO snippet view. Please copy the code and save it locally.*

**EDIT 2:** *Very weird. Please have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/KaareZ/50c3509f46ddf17240a9c45eef5fc36c#file-bar-html) and [video](https://streamable.com/11uih).*

I want to have a logo with a pulse animation, but I encountered a strange issue when I tested it with Safari 11.1.1. It works as expected on Firefox 60.0.2 and Chrome 67.0. If anyone are able to test Edge and IE, please post your results.

Below is a minified snippet that should replicate the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .foo-logo {
        height: 10rem;
        width: 10rem;
        margin: 2.5rem;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .foo-logo > p {
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .foo-animation {
        animation: pulse-animation 5s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes pulse-animation {
        0% {
            height: 10rem;
            width: 10rem;
            margin: 2.5rem;
        }
        50% {
            height: 15rem;
            width: 15rem;
            margin: 0rem;
        }
        100% {
            height: 10rem;
            width: 10rem;
            margin: 2.5rem;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="foo-logo"><p>No animation</p></div>
    <div class="foo-logo foo-animation"><p>Animation</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In case you don't have Safari available, here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced the issue in Safari and it looks like a Safari bug to me. So you can file a bugreport and wait for a fix.
Or try a workaround. I'd suggest updating your CSS the following way:

```
.foo-logo {
    font-size: 1rem; 
    /* 1em == font-size, so 1em == 1rem here and you can use em further */
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 2.5em;
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes pulse-animation {
    /* Yes, you can omit 0% and 100% here */

    50% {
        width: 15em;  /* 1em == 1rem */
        height: 15em;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.foo-logo > p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.foo-animation {
    animation: pulse-animation 5s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do the deal. I have reported the bug to Apple.

Comment: @KaareZ, happy to help!